# SQL select s subtr value and the real value

Tags: mysql, sql, apex

I am new to SQL and am looking to come up with a way to view the below example scenario.

I have a table with an ID field

```
**ID**        
123456.12.23.34.56        
098765.98.87.76        
123456.23.35.34.75        
654324.23.24.23.23
```

I am looking to have a select statement that would be ideal for a drop down select box in APEX, so in the drop down select box it would show the ID's based on their first six digits and the full ID code in ASC order.

FOR EXAMPLE the output would be:

```
098765
098765.98.87.76 
123456
123456.12.23.34.56               
123456.23.35.34.75        
654324.23.24.23.23
```

Since I am new to sql, I do not know the correct setup to get that select statement to work that would add the substr to the list of ID's but just have the one column with both the subtring and original value in it.
I am currently working on setting it up something like below, but need the values to be in one column and not duplicate (duplicate as in I dont want two substrings of the 123456 to show up).

```
select distinct substr(id,1,6), id      
from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select left(id, 6) as id
from t
union all
select id
from t
order by id;
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. I changed the left to a substr and it worked for me!